# Insert date or timestamp in Eclipse Editor

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I use different editors in eclipse and I search for a short cut to insert a date or configurable timestamp like the F5-Key in notepad.

Often I wrote text, comments and other textual stuff, where I need the actual date.

If you read my question carefully, you will realize, that templates doesn't solve my problem, because in pure text files a content assist like the Java Content Assist isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such short cut key is given in eclipse. You can try this [plugin](https://github.com/chandrayya/chandrayya-eclipse-plugins/blob/master/README.md)

Open any editor and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to insert current date and time. You can change the format of date and time in `Windows > Preferences > Chandrayya Plugins`